# Making a Video Splash Screen for an Android Based Game

Tags: java, android, video, file

I'm planning to make a video-based splash screen for the simple game app for Android under client's cigarette brand project. I was thinking if can this video file type, AVI, run on Android or not? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use the built in Media Player in Android, you can't play AVI files. [See the list of all supported formats.](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

If for some reason you can't convert the video to any of the supported formats, you will have to implement your own media player which has codecs etc. [You can take a look at FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android). It is possible to compile for Android.

Comment: How does FFmpeg works?

Comment: Just google for some samples, first link on google when looking for `ffmpeg android example`: https://github.com/churnlabs/android-ffmpeg-sample